# Is it my fault or travel agency to sell me ticket that requires me to get a visa during my transit

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, dublin, denied-boarding

My flight was supposed to be from Ho Chi Minh city (Vietnam) to Toronto, transiting In Dublin Doha.

Upon buying the ticket I googled if I need a transit visa and the answer was NO for my nationality. However, upon check-in for my flight I was denied to aboard because Dublin airport has two terminals. Terminal 1 requires a valid visa (not transit visa) and terminal 2 is for transiting passengers who may or may not need a transiting visa depending on the nationality. My first flight would land in terminal 2, which is good but my connecting flight would depart at terminal 1 which requires me to get out from terminal 2 and I am not allowed to unless I have a valid visa to enter this country. I was upset because when I bought the ticket, they tried to sell me connecting flights which made no sense and now saying that it is my responsibility to know about visa requirements. I was denied to check-in and missed my flight, and they refused to help.

Is there anyway I could fight for this, and make them responsible for my loss?

P/S: I did not know the terminals on my ticket after I paid for it and they sent me the ticket info. The ticket only less than 3 weeks, there was no time to work on the visa anyways. The site I bought the ticket from does not offer 24 hours cancellation policy, if I had canceled it, I would be charged nearly $1000 for fee. I mean how it be my fault when they put me in the situation like this?

Comment: Your googled result was wrong. [Transit (including Transfer Visa) Advice - Immigration Service Delivery](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/transit-including-transfer-visa-advice/): **When do I pass through border control?** Leaving the terminal building for any purpose, including in some cases having to transfer between terminals for a connecting flight

Comment: What is your citizenship and where is the travel agency based? Did you buy flights only or a package (e.g. flights+hotel)? Did you buy online on it a store? Local legislation probably varies a lot. A decent travel agent would (should?) have found out about this in a minute, Timatic is very clear about the rules. In many countries even if there’s no specific obligation for a travel agent to check this, professional have a duty towards consumers to provide advice, this may or may not apply in your case.

Comment: How is it possible that when you google you got "no" for your nationality? If I just google "Ireland transit visa", the first result I get is the official Irish Immigration website which explains everything very clearly. Anyway, airlines is not at all responsible here. As far as the travel agency goes, it depends on the agreement between you and possibly also the local laws (including consumer case law) where you and the agency are situated.

Comment: @ThomasCruise If it's [this webpage](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/transit-including-transfer-visa-advice/) it makes no sense to me. Assume the T2 04:00-16:00 hour condition is met. If the traveler is from Afghanistan, they are on the "Transit Visa Required Countries". What if the traveler is from Vietnam, which is not on the "required" list?

Comment: @user71659 If both conditions are met, and the traveler is from Vietnam, then they don't need a transit visa. The info on the webpage is as clear as it gets. The questioner here had their departing flight from terminal 1, so a transit visa is not relevant here. A tourist visa is required. (The flights should also be on the same PNR, else the airline operating the flight to Ireland will not consider the passenger to be a transit passenger)

Comment: @ThomasCruise No it's not clear because the page says "you can use a transit visa in this case. In all other situations you will need permission to enter the State". So a country not on the transit visa required list, is "all other situations". So it seems clear to me: if you meet the T2 requirement, and if you're from Afghanistan, you can use a transit visa. If you're from Vietnam, you need an entry visa. If somebody from Vietnam can use a transit visa (and Vietnam is on the entry visa required list), why is there a transit visa required list?

Comment: @user71659 It is as clear as glass, I am not sure where your confusion is. If you meet the T2 requirement and timing requirement and are from Vietnam, you DON'T need ANY visa. Transit visa is only relevant for airside transits and not when the person has to enter the country. That is how it is in all of the EU. The T2 and timing conditions determine whether you can make an airside transit. A transit visa will not be issued to a Vietnam citizen because it is irrelevant to them.

Comment: @ThomasCruise No, that isn't what the statement says "...you can use a transit visa in this case. In all other situations you will need permission to enter the State". Again, assuming T2 condition is met, somebody from Vietnam, according to you, does not need a transit visa (they aren't on the transit visa list). Ok fine. Then its an "all other situations," I'm not using a transit visa. It says right there that I need entry permission! So that statement directly contradicts you! Again, it's a deeply flawed explanation.

Comment: user71659 Neither is there any contradiction, neither is there any flaw in any explanation. You are not reading it properly. "All other situations" are situations where T2 condition and the timing condition is not met. In that case they need an entry permission, which is a tourist visa/visitor. A transit visa is not an entry permission. A transit visa is for airside transit, as already mentioned and not relevant to Vietnamese citizens.

Comment: Amy Ly, please next time sign in into the same account and edit the question as such, rather than as a different user.

Comment: @user71659 the logic works like this: if both of the flights are in T2 during the specified hours, you "can" use a transit visa; otherwise _a transit visa is not applicable for your transit._  If you meet this condition and your country isn't on the transit visa list, you don't need a visa at all.  If you don't meet this condition, then you need "permission to enter the state," which means that you might or might not need a _tourist_ visa, again depending on your nationality, but the list of countries is different.

Comment: @phoog I understand the logic Thomas Cruise is claiming, but I'm saying that's not the logic written in the linked page. The linked page says " In all other situations you will need permission to enter the State". A transit visa not being applicable is "all other situations". If they added a sentence like "If (T2 condition is met) and a transit visa is not required, you can connect without a visa. In all other situations..." then that would describe what you and Thomas Cruise claims it describes.

Comment: @user71659 "other situations" refers only to the T2 condition.  It applies to travelers who do not meet the T2 condition regardless of their nationality.  Nationality is not mentioned in that bullet point. Someone from Vietnam needs no visa if they meet the T2 condition but needs an entry visa if they don't meet the T2 condition.  Someone from Afghanistan needs a transit visa if they do meet it and an entry visa if they don't.  Someone from Canada does not need a visa in any case.

Comment: @phoog Then Who Needs to Apply should say "Transit passengers _with nationalities listed below_ making connections at Dublin Airport... In all other cases, _passengers with these nationalities_ need permission..." I understand what you're claiming, but it simply is not what is written. Again, it's poorly written webpage.

Comment: @user71659 I agree that it should say that and that it is poorly written, but still, if you follow what it says literally, you do not reach any other conclusion than the one I outlined above.  "All other circumstances" means "not meeting the T2 condition," period.  Only if you _do_ meet it do you need to proceed to the next bullet point to check whether your nationality is on that list.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there anyway I could fight for this, and make them responsible for my loss?

Unlikely. Knowing the visa rules and having the required documents is in fact your responsibility. The terminals should have been listed on your itinerary. Unless this information was unavailable to you until check-in (unlikely), you're out of luck.

Comment: Well, it comes down to the agreement between the travel agency and the individual. I could easily imagine some premium travel agencies will organise this stuff for you, or be very explicit about the stuff it was not able to organise.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no.

- The final decision to let someone in is with the immigration official on the spot. (Example: A visitor claims to be on holiday, but there are family documents and education diplomas rather than beach clothes in the luggage.) There is no way for the airline or travel agent to know if that will happen.
- Airlines are getting fined for carrying passengers who <strike>are denied entry</strike> have insufficient documentation. This is a way of governments to reduce asylum claims and the possibility of people in [legal limbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehran_Karimi_Nasseri). That leads to some airlines erring on the side of caution, leading to [complaints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryanair#Language_test) that people who **should** have been allowed entry were denied travel by the airline. Generally, the industry tries to find a balance between passengers who got turned down too early and those who got turned down too late.

So putting a duty to check visa *on the airline or travel agent* would force them to be much more careful in what they sell to whom. Either prices go up as they figure the cost of problematic sales into their business case, or people with less-than-perfect papers will not get tickets, or both.

It would have to be something in *domestic Vietnamese* business regulations to support your claim, not in *international* air travel regulations.

Comment: "Airlines are getting fined for carrying passengers who are denied entry": this is incorrect.  Airlines are fined for transporting passengers who do not have adequate documents.  If they were fined for passengers being denied entry then they would be searching passengers' luggage, subjecting them to criminal background checks, and examining their travel history to ensure they haven't committed immigration violations.  That's simply not how these fines work.